# Sum distinct values in a column based one criteria in another column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a df which includes the columns "country" and "label" and i want to sum the distinct values in the "label" column based on the values in the column "country". The desired output is shown in the column " final output". I have tried the countifs with 2 criteria but this just count the distinct the values . I also tried this SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$12=D2,MATCH($B$2:$B$12,$B$2:$B$12,0)),ROW($B$2:$B$12)-ROW($B$2)+1),$B$2:$B$12)) but it didnt work. I can do it with pivot but i prefer to do to it with formulas. Can anyone help? thank you

| country | label | Final Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Scotland | AAA | 2 |
| Scotland | AAA | 2 |
| Scotland | BBB | 2 |
| Spain | AAA | 1 |
| Spain | AAA | 1 |
| France | BBB | 3 |
| France | AAA | 3 |
| France | CCC | 3 |

Answer (score 3):

With ms365, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=MAP(A2:A9,LAMBDA(x,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:B9,A2:A9=x)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this solution?
You count for every code how much times it appears for that country, and you take the inverse of it.
Like this, when you add it, you get the amount of distinct values, as you can easily see here:

| Criterium | Value | Count | 1/count | Sum of 1/count for this criterium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| crit | A | 5 | 1/5 | 1/5+1/5+1/5+1/5+1/5+1/3+1/3+1/3+1 = 3 |
| crit | A | 5 | 1/5 |  |
| crit | A | 5 | 1/5 |  |
| crit | A | 5 | 1/5 |  |
| crit | A | 5 | 1/5 |  |
| crit | B | 3 | 1/3 |  |
| crit | B | 3 | 1/3 |  |
| crit | B | 3 | 1/3 |  |
| crit | C | 1 | 1 |  |

Hence, you get the following screenshot:

[image]

Used formulae:

```
cell "C2" : =1/COUNTIFS(A$2:A$9,A2,B$2:B$9,B2)
cell "D2" : =SUMIF(A$2:A$9,A2,C$2:C$9)
```

(I bet there's a way to simplify this, but I haven't enough coffee yet to find it :-) )

Have fun

Answer (score 1):

### Count Unique

```
=LET(Countries,A2:A9,Labels,B2:B9,
    uCountries,UNIQUE(Countries),
    uFinals,BYROW(uCountries,LAMBDA(uCountry,
        ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(Labels,Countries=uCountry))))),
INDEX(uFinals,XMATCH(Countries,uCountries)))
```

[image]